# Time complexities of three algorithms are given. Which should execute the slowest for large value of N?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Options given:

```
(a) O(2N)
(b) O(N)
(c) O(logN)
(d) O(n^2)
```

I have encountered this questions in the online examination. The Correct option they are mentioning is O(logN). But in my perspective it should be O(2N), because the "n^2" they given, "n" is in lowercase, otherwise it should be O(N^2). Someone help me with the proper answer.

[image]

Comment: Upper case? Lower case? The site asked you a junk question with no definitive answer. Perhaps you should find yourself a better testing site.

Comment: Probably, it's a *typo* and the question should be read as `(d) O(N^2)`

Comment: Three algorithms? It looks to me like they added a 4th and didn't bother to update the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare complexities `O(A(n))` and `O(B(n))` you should compute the *limit*:

```
lim A(n)/B(n) = ?
  n->+Inf
```

you can have *three* possible outcomes:

```
   0      A (infinitely) faster than B
+Inf      A (infinitely) slower than B
   v > 0  A~B; A is v times slower than B
```

In your case:

```
lim(n^2/2n) = lim(n^2/n) = lim(n^2/log(n)) = +Inf
  n->+Inf       n->+Inf      n->+Inf
```

that's why `(d) O(n^2)` is the *slowest* algorithm among `(a)..(d)` ones.

The *fastest* algorithm is `(c) O(log(n))`, (use [L'Hospital's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) to compute the limits):

```
lim(log(n)/2n) = lim(log(n)/n) = lim(log(n)/n^2) = 0
  n->+Inf          n->+Inf         n->+Inf
```

Finally, the algorithms ordered from fastest to slowest:

```
(c) O(log(n)), (b) O(n), (a) O(2*n), (d) O(n^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that (d) should be the slowest, as shown in this plot:

[image]